How come original Head of the linked list changes while traversing over it in Python? Am I doing anything wrong?
In the below code, I'm not changing the value of Head still why am I not able to retain the value of Head?The input is a LinkedList: [5, 4, 2, 1]
class Solution:
    def pairSum(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> int:
        superhead = head
        print("Head starting:", head)
        curr2, prev2 = head, None
        print("curr2:", curr2)
        print("Superhead:", superhead)
        print("Head before while loop:", head)
        count = max = 0
        while curr2:
            print("\nInside while: Head", head)
            temp2 = curr2.next
            curr2.next = prev2
            prev2 = curr2
            curr2 = temp2
        print("\nHead end:", head)

Output:
Head starting: ListNode{val: 5, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}}}
curr2: ListNode{val: 5, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}}}
Superhead: ListNode{val: 5, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}}}
Head before while loop: ListNode{val: 5, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}}}

Inside while: Head ListNode{val: 5, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}}}
Inside while: Head ListNode{val: 5, next: None}
Inside while: Head ListNode{val: 5, next: None}
Inside while: Head ListNode{val: 5, next: None}

Head end: ListNode{val: 5, next: None}

I tried printing the values of Head in the while loop and see it changing there.

Why are you modifying the list if you just want to traverse it?

Your loop reverses the linked list. That means that the node that was the head, will become the tail.
Here is a visualisation of your example. It starts like this
   head  
     ↓ 
     5 → 4 → 3 → 2 → 1 → None
     ↑
   curr2
   

After the first iteration, we have:
     head  
       ↓ 
None ← 5   4 → 3 → 2 → 1 → None
           ↑
         curr2

The node with value 5 was mutated, because we did curr2.next = prev2 and at that time curr2 had a reference to the same node as head.
After the second iteration:
     head  
       ↓ 
None ← 5 ← 4   3 → 2 → 1 → None
               ↑
             curr2

And so it continues until curr2 is None:
     head  
       ↓ 
None ← 5 ← 4 ← 3 ← 2 ← 1   None
                            ↑
                          curr2

So if you now look at head and follow the next attributes, you'll immediately get to None. The other nodes cannot be reached via head. This is expected, because the node with value 5 is now the tail node.
The node that really has become the head of the list is the node that previously was the tail. If you wanted to print all the nodes starting from the new head, then you should start at prev2, which after the loop has a reference to the node with value 1.

Any feedback to this answer, @UtkirnaShinde?
